# MySQL / MariaDB place COUNT(*) in equation

Tags: mysql, count, mariadb, equation, mysql-variables

I'm trying to get the number of rows in a table or column and place that value inside an equation, like this:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myCalculatedColumn = COUNT(*) / (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum)
WHERE 0 = (@rownum:=0)
```

Unfortunately, I get an error 1111 "Invalid use of group function". I've also tried:

```
SET @c = COUNT(*);
UPDATE myTable 
SET myCalculatedColumn = @c / (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum)
WHERE 0 = (@rownum:=0)
```

But this produces the same error.

How can I place `COUNT(*)` (or a programmatically equivalent operation) into an equation?

Comment: How could you possibly expect `SET @c = COUNT(*);` to work? How is it supposed to know what to count when setting the variable?

Comment: Yeah fair point that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join with a subquery that gets the count. You can also initialize the `@rownum` variable there as well.

```
UPDATE myTable AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, @rownum := 0 FROM myTable) AS c
SET myCalculatedColumn = count / (@rownum := 1 + @rownum)
```

If you don't want to do a cross join, you can use the subquery when setting `@c`. You just have to tell `COUNT(*)` what table to count from.

```
SET @c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable);
SET @rownum = 0;
UPDATE myTable 
SET myCalculatedColumn = @c / (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum);
```

Note that the order that it assigns to `myCalculatedColumn` will be arbitrary and unpredictable unless you also have an `ORDER BY` clause.